# Mysql update with counter

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever i try to run this query

```
UPDATE AddItem SET IUID=IUID+1 WHERE UID=1
```

I am expecting to see an incremental number

```
1    
2    
3
```

But what i actually get is

```
1    
1    
1
```

Comment: What are you printing? is it IUID or UID?

Comment: trying to print IUID

Comment: I'd expect an UPDATE statement to return a number of rows affected, not a list. We see two different columns referenced, IUID and UID. The expression `IUID+1` is going to take the current value of the `IUID` column from the current row, evaluate that in a numeric context, and add 1 to it. The `IUID =` assignment is going to take the value for the expression and store that back into the `IUID` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variables. **[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fd3fd/1)**

```
update AddItem
cross join (SELECT @id := 0 ) as a
set id = @id := @id + 1
where id =1;
```